# Laravel - javascript issue with pound and euro

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, special-characters, encode

I have this code:

```
$(".range").ionRangeSlider({
    min: '{{$article->lowest_bid}}',
    max: '{{$article->price}}',
    from: obj.price,
    step: 0.1,
    max_postfix: ' (usual rate)',
    prefix: '{{$article->cur}}',
    onChange: function (data) {
        $('.price').val(data.from);

    },
    onFinish: function (data) {
      var curr = '{{$article->cur}}';
      $('.runload').text('PLACE BID ' +curr+(data.from).toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

So this function work good and show sign £ and other ... but onFinish function there just I get `'PLACE BID &pound;33.00'`

Why {{$article->cur}} from database dont work on my onFinish ?
How to solve it?

on line: prefix: '{{$article->cur}}', work good and show sign but onFinish dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pound and euro signs are being rendered as their [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML), ie the escaped format so they don't interfere with code.

To display them correctly, you could replace the `.text()` call with `.html()`:

```
onFinish: function (data) {
  var curr = '{{$article->cur}}';
  $('.runload').html('PLACE BID ' +curr+(data.from).toFixed(2));
}
```

This will treat the `data.from` as HTML, so will render the HTML entities correctly.

Comment: Yes, true but this is text into button... so I will remove whole button